# Cannot install Python old version(including ~3.9) in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: python, 22.10, pgadmin

Recently, I updated my ubuntu version to 22.10.
I researched online to install python old version in ubuntu 22.10.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`
This command does not work 22.10. How can I install old python version?
Why I am going to install python old version is, already installed pgadmin is not working in Ubuntu 22.10 and   solution is to install old python version according to my research.
It will be better how pgadmin can work again.

Comment: That PPA only support 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04. It doesn't support 22.10 and never will. You shouldn't mess with the system's python anyway or you'll break pretty much everything that relies on it, i.e. a huge part of the OS including apt. Some reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565403/how-to-prove-installing-different-python-version-wont-interfere-with-the-system

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto. Why pgadmin does not support 22.10 and will not? And what is the solution for pgadmin?

Comment: PPAs support the releases their maintainers decide to support, that's all. In the case of the "deadsnakes" PPA it's easy to see they intend to support LTS only. So, if still maintained then, the next expected release to have support will be 24.04 (April 2024). 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 will occur before 24.04 but they AREN'T Long Term Support releases.

Comment: Oh, then should I wait until April 2024, if I don't install OS again?

Comment: No. Please read the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find it useful to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage different python versions on one host.

`Basic GitHub checkout` installation method in README section works pretty well for linux distributions.

After that, you will be able to install different python versions with `pyenv install <version>`, set some local python interpreter for the directory with `pyenv local <version>`, global one with `pyenv global <version>`